# How to convert List<string[]> into List<int[]

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist, type-conversion

Can I convert an `List<string[]>` into an `List<int[]>`?

Or do I have to convert the string array into int array and then put it into a new List like this?

```
List<string[]> arrayStringList = new List<string[]>();
List<int[]> arrayIntList = new List<int[]>();

foreach(string[] stringArray in arrayStringList)
{
    int[] iArr = stringArray.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
    arrayIntList.Add(iArr);
}
```

Comment: this works and is very clear as to what you are trying to do. there's no built in facility for that.

Comment: There's nothing to "convert" as strings aren't integers. They need parsing, which means you *have* to call `int.Parse` one way or another. You don't need that `foreach` though, you can use LINQ with both lists and arrays, eg `arrayStringList .Select(arr=>stringArray.Select(int.Parse).ToArray()).ToList()`

Comment: Despite the fact that your input-list is empty I can´t see any problem here. What results do you get? Any exceptions? Errors? Unexpected results?

Comment: @Franck I searched very long to find a Question like this. I see that this is a duplicate but the Title of the other Question is misleading so I couldn't find it.

Comment: @N.Kewitsch there is literally at least 1 question per week about this and that's just in the C# tag. I just picked one of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In one line

```
arrayIntList = arrayStringList.Select(x => x.Select(int.Parse).ToArray()).ToList();
```